# Random indexing in python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a `(4,10000)` x array and `(1,10000)` y array. I'm trying to shuffle them by randomly indexing as

```
random_idxs = np.random.choice(m,(m,1), replace=False)
```

I'm trying to do something like below but the structure is eluding me.

```
x_shuffled = x[random_idxs]
y_shuffled = y[random_idxs]
```

Comment: What is `m` here?

Comment: Why not just use `shuffle`?

Comment: Are these numpy arrays or python lists?

Comment: Also, what happened when you tried the code you showed us? An exception? The wrong results? Your computer ran off to Antarctica with the toaster?

Comment: Mine was to Siberia. And it *was* the toaster. There goes my last available Doom port.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Shuffle the columns into the same order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy already has a [`shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) function to do what you want.

Assuming you want to shuffle the columns into the same order, as your question implies:

```
idx = np.arange(x.shape[-1])  # or x.shape[1]
np.random.shuffle(idx)
```

Now you can apply the shuffled index to your arrays:

```
x = x[..., idx]  #  or [:, idx] for 2D-only
y = y[..., idx]
```

Comment: You have an "either" without the "or" part. (I'm guessing it was "or just shuffle the arrays directly", but wouldn't that require putting `x, y` in an array together so you can shuffle the transpose of it, or something similar?)

Comment: @abarnert. I had a pointless blurb about lists. Got rid of the whole section. Fixed now.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: This worked fine :) I was applying the shuffle() before, albeit wrongly.